# Java regular expressions: performance and alternative

Tags: java, regex

Recently I have been had to search a number of string values to see which one matches a certain pattern. Neither the number of string values nor the pattern itself is clear until a search term has been entered by the user.

The problem is I have noticed each time my application runs the following line:

```
if (stringValue.matches(rexExPattern)) {
    // do something so simple
}
```

it takes about 40 micro second. No need to say when the number of string values exceeds a few thousands, it'll be too slow.

The pattern is something like:

```
"A*B*C*D*E*F*"
```

where `A~F` are just examples here, but the pattern is some thing like the above. *Please note** that the pattern actually changes per search. For example `"A*B*C*"` may change to `"W*D*G*A*"`.

I wonder if there is a better substitution for the above pattern or, more generally, an alternative for Java regular expressions.

Comment: Is this really not meeting your performance requirements? Is this truly the bottleneck in your code? A few hundred * 4 microseconds = a few milliseconds.

Comment: I may not calculate correctly. but normally it takes 10 seconds per search. I'll edit my question in a few seconds.

Comment: The solution is most likely not a faster regex, and more likely a better search algorithm. If you gave more details about your actual usage, you may get some better advice. Also, your math still doesn't add up. A few hundred * 40 microseconds != 10 seconds. Where did your profiling show you that the bottleneck was?

Comment: Also have a look on [boolean sequence](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/BooleanSequence). It currently supports limited RE symbols but it is fast and flexible and give options to become more faster.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Regular expressions in Java are compiled into an internal data structure. This compilation is the time-consuming process. Each time you invoke the method `String.matches(String regex)`, the specified regular expression is compiled again.

So you should compile your regular expression only once and reuse it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPattern);
for(String value : values) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create the Matcher ahead of time as well as the Pattern.  Just feed the constructor an empty string to start with, then inside the loop you can use `Matcher.reset(value)` to apply it.  It won't have nearly as much impact on performance as precompiling the Pattern, but if performance is really critical, it will help.

Comment: thank you for your help. But the problem is the pattern changes per search. for example "A*B*C" may changes to "E*B*C*W*". I'll edit my question right now.

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani The point was to compile the regex once per search, precisely as the example in this answer clearly illustrates.

Comment: @AlanMoore As a caution: `Matcher` objects are NOT thread safe per [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).  Therefore, the reset method you've describe is likely dangerous in high-performance, multi-threaded scenarios.  I'm not sure if reusing the Matcher object is beneficial enough to take that risk.  Reusing the precompiled Pattern is definitely safe and good practice.

Comment: Yes, guys, you should not vote up @AlanMoore comment. You should not use the same instance of matcher! It's not thread-safe!

Answer (score 36):

Consider the following (quick and dirty) test:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test3 {

    // time that tick() was called
    static long tickTime;

    // called at start of operation, for timing
    static void tick () {
        tickTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    // called at end of operation, prints message and time since tick().
    static void tock (String action) {
        long mstime = (System.nanoTime() - tickTime) / 1000000;
        System.out.println(action + ": " + mstime + "ms");
    }

    // generate random strings of form AAAABBBCCCCC; a random 
    // number of characters each randomly repeated.
    static List<String> generateData (int itemCount) {

        Random random = new Random();
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        long mean = 0;

        for (int n = 0; n < itemCount; ++ n) {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            int characters = random.nextInt(7) + 1;
            for (int k = 0; k < characters; ++ k) {
                char c = (char)(random.nextInt('Z' - 'A') + 'A');
                int rep = random.nextInt(95) + 5;
                for (int j = 0; j < rep; ++ j)
                    s.append(c);
                mean += rep;
            }
            items.add(s.toString());
        }

        mean /= itemCount;
        System.out.println("generated data, average length: " + mean);

        return items;

    }

    // match all strings in items to regexStr, do not precompile.
    static void regexTestUncompiled (List<String> items, String regexStr) {

        tick();

        int matched = 0, unmatched = 0;

        for (String item:items) {
            if (item.matches(regexStr))
                ++ matched;
            else
                ++ unmatched;
        }

        tock("uncompiled: regex=" + regexStr + " matched=" + matched + 
             " unmatched=" + unmatched);

    }

    // match all strings in items to regexStr, precompile.
    static void regexTestCompiled (List<String> items, String regexStr) {

        tick();

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regexStr).matcher("");
        int matched = 0, unmatched = 0;

        for (String item:items) {
            if (matcher.reset(item).matches())
                ++ matched;
            else
                ++ unmatched;
        }

        tock("compiled: regex=" + regexStr + " matched=" + matched + 
             " unmatched=" + unmatched);

    }

    // test all strings in items against regexStr.
    static void regexTest (List<String> items, String regexStr) {

        regexTestUncompiled(items, regexStr);
        regexTestCompiled(items, regexStr);

    }

    // generate data and run some basic tests
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        List<String> items = generateData(1000000);
        regexTest(items, "A*");
        regexTest(items, "A*B*C*");
        regexTest(items, "E*C*W*F*");

    }

}
```

Strings are random sequences of 1-8 characters with each character occurring 5-100 consecutive times (e.g. "AAAAAAGGGGGDDFFFFFF"). I guessed based on your expressions.

Granted this might not be representative of your data set, but the timing estimates for applying those regular expressions to 1 million randomly generates strings of average length 208 each on my modest 2.3 GHz dual-core i5 was:

```
Regex      Uncompiled    Precompiled
A*          0.564 sec     0.126 sec
A*B*C*      1.768 sec     0.238 sec
E*C*W*F*    0.795 sec     0.275 sec
```

Actual output:

```
generated data, average length: 208
uncompiled: regex=A* matched=6004 unmatched=993996: 564ms
compiled: regex=A* matched=6004 unmatched=993996: 126ms
uncompiled: regex=A*B*C* matched=18677 unmatched=981323: 1768ms
compiled: regex=A*B*C* matched=18677 unmatched=981323: 238ms
uncompiled: regex=E*C*W*F* matched=25495 unmatched=974505: 795ms
compiled: regex=E*C*W*F* matched=25495 unmatched=974505: 275ms
```

Even without the speedup of precompiled expressions, and even considering that the results vary wildly depending on the data set and regular expression (and even considering that I broke a basic rule of proper Java performance tests and forgot to prime HotSpot first), this is very fast, and I still wonder if the bottleneck is truly where you think it is.

After switching to precompiled expressions, if you still are not meeting your **actual performance requirements**, do some profiling. If you find your bottleneck is still in your search, consider implementing a more optimized search algorithm.

For example, assuming your data set is like my test set above: If your data set is known ahead of time, reduce each item in it to a smaller string key by removing repetitive characters, e.g. for "AAAAAAABBBBCCCCCCC", store it in a map of some sort keyed by "ABC". When a user searches for "A*B*C*" (presuming your regex's are in that particular form), look for "ABC" items. Or whatever. It highly depends on your scenario.

Comment: If I "saved your life" because you switched to compiled regex's, you should really mark @Seelenvirtuose's answer, who suggested it very clearly, as the correct one.