# Search for Strings that matches regex in very huge Set or List in Java

Tags: java, regex, search, set, large-files

My file with all words is about 60MB and searching for rhyme now takes about minute.

How can I faster searching process?

Split text file into at example a.txt, b.txt, c.txt (Every file with words starting at a/b/c...)?

I guess putting it in MySQL and querying with

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE word LIKE '%rhyme'
```

will be slower.

I will be pleased if it will search for rhymes in about 10 seconds or less, because I want to use this API with Angular CLI frontend and use it to suggest rhymes while typing text in textarea.

Thanks for help!

```
package pl.kamilkoszykowski.dopewriter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public class Controller {

    Set<String> dictionary = getDictionary(); // SET WITH WORDS

    @GetMapping("/rhyme/{word}")
    public Set<String> rhymes(@PathVariable String word) throws InterruptedException {

        String regex = "\\b[A-Za-z]*" + word + "\\b"; // RHYME TO SEARCH FOR IN DICTIONARY SET

        Set<String> rhymesList = new HashSet<>();

        int numRunnables = 64;
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(numRunnables, true);
        RejectedExecutionHandler handler = new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy();
        ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(numRunnables, numRunnables, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue, handler);

        for (String a : dictionary) {
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (a.matches(regex)) {
                        rhymesList.add(a);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        while (executor.isTerminated() == false){
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }

        return rhymesList;
    }

    public Set<String> getDictionary() { // READING TXT FILE
        try {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(Files.readString(Paths.get("src/main/resources/dictionary.txt")).split(",")));
            return new HashSet<>(list);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have just one static file that will be used during the runtime?

Comment: try these [tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829892/java-regular-expressions-performance-and-alternative). It can be really beneficial not to recompile the regex for every match.

Comment: I forgot about it Jakob. I'll change and test

Comment: Still about minute. I don't know what change. Maybe I split this set into few smaller

Comment: What is stored in the dictionary? Are that only words or whole sentences? If it's only words you would better use `a.endsWith(word)` instead of using a regex.

Comment: Only words. Java reads .txt file with words separated by ",". I'll try with endsWith and eventually split dictionary into multiple files

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a Collection itself is a time-consuming process. Multiple ways to solve:

1. Use java streams. -- Faster to implement and has better speed than with custom thread pool executor.
2. Keep the data sorted in Set. Do a sorting technique to get the results faster. Still won't be faster enough.
3. Store the data in [`Trie`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-a-dictionary-using-trie/) data structure and get all the words under the root that matches the regex. -- Recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I changed executor code part to this

```
executor1.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (String a : dictionary) {
                    if (a.endsWith(word)) {
                        rhymesList.add(a);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

and works. Sorry for time, that I've taken from you